# Group velocity and calculating wavelength

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wave-particle-duality

> A stone tossed into a body of water creates a disturbance at the point of impact that lasts for Dt = 4.0s. Measurements indicates that the wave speed is v = 25 cm/s.
>
> (a) Over what distance on the surface of water does the wave group extend?
>
> (b) An observer counts 12 wave crests in the group.Use the classical uncertainty relationship to estimate the precision with which the wavelength could be determined.

My attempt: the group distance is calculated by multiplying wave speed*the time impact
(b) there are 12 crest over the distance of 100 cm hence the wavelength will be 100/12.
I am not sure about this is there any mistake in this?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)